# BaseActivity for NavigationDrawer gives NullPointerException when accessing views

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I have been trying to add the `NavigationDrawer` to multiple `Activities`, but I keep running into errors. I read almost everything that I could find, and it seems that the easiest way to do this is to create a `BaseActivity`, and extend every other activity that wants the `NavigationDrawer`. This is what I have put together based on tutorials that I found here.

**BaseActivity.java**

```
   package com.example.eddie.drawerapp2;
    //I did not include the imports to make this shorter

   abstract  public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
{
    protected FrameLayout frameLayout;
    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    private NavigationView navView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.base_activity);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        // Here, ask the derived class for the layout resource to inflate into the content frame layout
        View stubView = inflater.inflate(getContentLayoutResId(), frameLayout, false);
        frameLayout.addView(stubView, lp);


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawer = findViewById(R.id.layout_drawer);


        android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
       drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
       toggle.syncState();

        frameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
        navView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


    }

    abstract  protected  int getContentLayoutResId();

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
// Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

**base_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout_drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    android:layout_gravity="left">



    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
        />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answers said that the `MainActivity` doesn't need to do anything to use the `NavigationDrawer` if it extends the `BaseActivity`

**MainActivity.java**

```
    //skipped imports to make this shorter
    public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity{

    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    private NavigationView navView;

    @Override
    protected int getContentLayoutResId() {
        return R.layout.activity_main;
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="TextView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The error is this

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.eddie.drawerapp2/com.example.eddie.drawerapp2.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.FrameLayout.addView(android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams)' on a null object reference
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2763)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2824)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1546)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6351)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:896)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.FrameLayout.addView(android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams)' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.eddie.drawerapp2.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:38)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6775)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2716)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2824) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1546) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6351) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:896) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:786)
```

It point to this line in `BaseActivity`:

```
    frameLayout.addView(stubView, lp);
```

Comment: Why don't you use fragments instead?

Comment: I strongly suggest you to play with fragments, and not activities. Activities are not supposed to share ui components

Comment: @AshishKumar sure, why not, I am open to anything, as long as it works. So, If i do it like this, would than each of the `NavigationDrawer` items be a seprate fragment, or would every activity that has the navigation drawer be a fragment shown in one activity. I think you can post this as an answer, with a slightly more detailed explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you try to call your custom `setContentView`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.onCreateDrawer();
}
```

But that null checks `frameLayout`:

```
@Override
public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
    if (frameLayout != null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        View stubView = inflater.inflate(layoutResID, frameLayout, false);
        frameLayout.addView(stubView, lp);

    }
}
```

Which is not actually initialized until later:

```
protected void onCreateDrawer() {
    frameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
}
```

So, of course, you have not inflated a layout from which to get your DrawerLayout, hence your crash.

I would suggest you spend time learning how to [debug your application](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html).

Hope that helps!

---

**UPDATE**:

OK, I thought pointing you to your problem would help you solve the issue on your own. Here's my suggestion:

BaseActivity should set up the base layout that the derived class will inflate into (notice that we do not override `setContentView`):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.base_activity);
    onCreateDrawer();

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    // Here, ask the derived class for the layout resource to inflate into the content frame layout
    View stubView = inflater.inflate(getContentLayoutResId(), frameLayout, false);
    frameLayout.addView(stubView, lp);
}

abstract protect int getContentLayoutResId();
```

Then your MainActivity is just:

```
@Override
protected int getContentLayoutResId() {
    return R.layout.activity_main;
}
```

Comment: This talks about the problem, but does not show how to fix it.

Comment: OK, I updated my answer. In the future I'd suggest you not downvote someone's answer when they're taking the time to try to help you, as that made me reconsider whether I would bother wasting my time updating my answer.

Comment: Oh I don't have enough points to down vote. I will up vote if this fixes my problem though.

Comment: Finally works, thank you so much. I appreciate this, on a personal level. Finally works after over 2 weeks of trial and error

Comment: Where do I put the code that would normally go into the `onCreate()`? is it just `getContentLayoutResId()`?

Comment: Oh, sorry, assumed you'd downvoted. If you need to do more in your MainActivity, then just override onCreate, call super, and do what you need (but don't call setContentView since the base class does that)